# iterate inside data : [ ] in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code which works fine,

```
 Morris.Bar({
            element: 'barchart',
            axes: true,
            data: [ json.bar.bar1 ],
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
            labels: ['Facebook', 'LinkedIn', 'Google+'],
            barColors: ['#707f9b', '#455064', '#242d3c']
        });
```

THE JSON

```
{
"bar"  : 
{
"bar1" :    {
   "x" : "2013 Q1",
   "y" : "9",
   "z" : "6",
   "a" : "8"
        },
"bar2" :    {
   "x" : "2013 Q2",
   "y" : "5",
   "z" : "7",
   "a" : "3"
        },
"bar3" :    {
   "x" : "2013 Q3",
   "y" : "8",
   "z" : "9",
   "a" : "6"
        },
"bar4" :    {
   "x" : "2013 Q4",
   "y" : "7",
   "z" : "9",
   "a" : "8"
        }
}  
}
```

However when I embed a loop i'm shown syntax error in dreamweaver. Also the output is not rendered on the web page.

```
 Morris.Bar({
            element: 'barchart',
            axes: true,
            data: [
            for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
            {
            json.bar.bar + i + ','
            }
            ],
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
            labels: ['Facebook', 'LinkedIn', 'Google+'],
            barColors: ['#707f9b', '#455064', '#242d3c']
        });
```

The overall idea is to make it look like this

```
Morris.Bar({
            element: 'barchart',
            axes: true,
            data: [ json.bar.bar1,
                    json.bar.bar2,
                    json.bar.bar3,
                    json.bar.bar4 ],
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
            labels: ['Facebook', 'LinkedIn', 'Google+'],
            barColors: ['#707f9b', '#455064', '#242d3c']
        });
```

Comment: What are `json.bar.bar[1-4]`?

Comment: You can't have a for loop inside an array definition.

Comment: you need to create array outside of `Morris.Bar` object...then simply pass the array to `data`

Comment: you should learn JavaScript first..

Comment: seriously @wong2 I agree to your comment, I'm very bad at javascript but its a task given to me :| I tried something because, Something is better than nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have a for loop inside an array.

You have do it outside.

Or in ECMAScript5, you could do with:

```
data: Object.keys(json.bar).map(function(key) {return json.bar[key]}),
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
data: (function() {
    var newBar = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        newBar.push(json.bar["bar"+i]); //for the current structure of your json.bar object            
    }
    return newBar
})();
```

You might want to use an array, `json.bar`, for your bar values. Then you can do `newBar.push(json.bar[i])` instead (be mindful of the `i` values though, the index of the first element would be 0)

Comment: Good one... But we don't know whether that is a string or not.

Comment: @thefourtheye What do you mean?

Comment: This did not work but what @xdazz wrote worked proplery,

data: Object.keys(json.bar).map(function(key) {return json.bar[key]}),

Comment: What this code does is get the keys for data.bar with Object.keys(). Then we use map to return an array. Each iteration of map() will go through each key obtained by Object.keys. In this code, it returns the object in data.bar assigned to that key.

Comment: @AshikBasheer I know what xdazz's code is doing(and his is probably the better way of doing it) but mine would also work. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/TduZL/)